# How to use VueJS to highlight an item in a list

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm pretty new to VueJS and I'm trying to use it to make a playlist app.  The first part of making a playlist was pretty simple:

```
var playlist = [];
var playlistCurrentlyPlaying = 0;

// TODO: Highlight currently playing song
Vue.component('playlist-item', {
    template: "<li class='playlist-item'>{{ text }}</li>",
    props: ['text']
});

var playlistElement = new Vue({
    el: '#playlist',
    data: {
        playlist: playlist
    }
});

// Add song to the playlist
playlist.push({filepath:"url/to/file", artist:"The Band"})
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<ul id="playlist" >
    <li v-for="song in playlist" is="playlist-item" :text="song.filepath">
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `playlistCurrentlyPlaying` variable is used by other functions to keep track of what song in the playlist is being used.  I want to use Vue to highlight currently playing song in the playlist as well.  I'm using Vue2 and just cannot figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Vue.JS myself, but could you not add another property to you playlist-item component that indicates whether that item is currently playing (active)?

```
<li v-for="(song, index) in playlist" is="playlist-item" :text="song.filepath" :active="index == playlistCurrentlyPlaying">
```